# Model binding error with custom MediaTypeFormatter in ASP.Net Web API

Tags: model-binding, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the `JsonNetFormatter` found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/18/using-json-net-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx) with a Web API beta project hosted in an ASP.Net MVC 4 beta site and discovered that model binding seems to work slightly differently than when I use the default `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`. After switching over to the `JsonNetFormatter` model binding seems to disreguard parameters set in the URL. For example, the following code works fine with the default `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`, but when I use the `JsonNetFormatter` this error is thrown:

`"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Put(Int32, WebAPISpike.Website.Api.Model.PutLesson)'...`

**JsonNetFormatter**

```
public class JsonNetFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    private JsonSerializerSettings _jsonSerializerSettings;

    public JsonNetFormatter(JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings)
    {
        _jsonSerializerSettings = jsonSerializerSettings ?? new JsonSerializerSettings();

        // Fill out the mediatype and encoding we support
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
        Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);
    }

    protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(IKeyValueModel))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override Task<object> OnReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream stream, HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders, FormatterContext formatterContext)
    {
        // Create a serializer
        JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(_jsonSerializerSettings);

        // Create task reading the content
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding))
            {
                using (JsonTextReader jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
                {
                    return serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader, type);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected override Task OnWriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream stream, HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders, FormatterContext formatterContext, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        // Create a serializer
        JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(_jsonSerializerSettings);

        // Create task writing the serialized content
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding))
            {
                using (JsonTextWriter jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, value);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Web API Config**

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();  
serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonNetFormatter(serializerSettings));
```

**Controller**

```
public class LessonsController : ApiController {
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, PutLesson updates) {
        // get lesson by id and update it with new values in from updates
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class PutLesson {
    public string LessonName { get; set; }
    public string Overview { get; set; }
}
```

I can work around the issue by moving the id parameter into my `PutLesson` model and then setting it there, but then it isn't the URI that identifies the resource, it is the request body. Is there something missing in the `JsonNetFormatter` implementation or my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in WebAPI beta (it happens with all kinds of custom MediaTypeFormatters, it is planned to be fixed in next version). There are two workarounds for this issue at this point. The most "clean" seems to be adding an ActionFilter which will handle binding those parameters for you. You can read more about it here:

- [Bug with Binding Route Values when using a custom MediaTypeFormatter](http://geekswithblogs.net/jdothoffman/archive/2012/03/06/mvc-4-beta-web-api-bug-with-binding-route-values.aspx)

You can find there also a link to discussion which contains the second workaround.